# Counting the number of functions $\delta\,:\,\left(Q\backslash F\right)\times\Gamma\to Q\times\Gamma\times\left\{ L,R,S\right\}$

Tags: combinatorics

It's a question in computability theory but since it's really about counting, I'll try to ask in here. Count the number of turning machines that have different $\delta$ function over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$. The function is $\delta\,:\,\left(Q\backslash F\right)\times\Gamma\to Q\times\Gamma\times\left\{ L,R,S\right\} $ where $\Sigma=\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ and $\Gamma=\left\{ 0,1, \flat\right\} $ ($\flat$ is a special char that represents "empty char" - but it does not matter).

My textbook says (noted that $|Q|=t$):
$$
\delta\,:\,\overset{t}{\overbrace{\left(Q\backslash F\right)}}\times\overset{3}{\overbrace{\Gamma}}\to\overset{t}{\overbrace{Q}}\times\overset{3}{\overbrace{\Gamma}}\times\overset{3}{\overbrace{\left\{ L,R,S\right\} }}
$$
This means that there are at most $(9t)^{3t}$ machines/$\delta$-functions. I'm trying to figure why it's $(9t)^{3t}$. I started counting:
$$t\cdot 3\cdot t\cdot 3\cdot 3=27t^2$$
But apparently it's wrong. So basically I think I leak of understanding on how to count the number of functions. How do I "count" (technically) and get to $(9t)^{3t}$, combinatorically specking?

It looks like if $f\,:\, A\to B$ then the number of functions is at most $|B|^{|A|}$. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true. Notice that if you do $|B|\cdot |A|,$ then you are essentially pairing elements of $B$ and elements of $A$. So, your formula, would imply that a functions is just **one** pair. On the other hand $|B|^{|A|}$ is like taking a $|A|$ copies of $B$ and this is a function, you can make a bijection as follows:
$$\varphi : \{f:A\longrightarrow B\}\longrightarrow B\times B\times \cdots \times B$$ by assigning
$$\varphi(f)=(f(a_1),\cdots ,f(a_{|A|})),$$
where $A=\{a_1,\cdots ,a_{|A|}\}.$ Notice that this is functional because you can not assign two objects of $B$ to the same component of the vector.

Comment: In general, if $f\,:\, A\to B$ then the number of functions is equal $|B|^{|A|}$ or is it at most $|B|^{|A|}$?

Comment: it is equal. Show that the  function $\phi$ is a bijection and you can conclude this. @vesii